# Listview not shown in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

I have tried to implement the listview in asp.net. But i can't get the output. where i make the mistake i don't know. pls help me.

**My Model**

[image]

**ASPX**

```
 <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server">
             <ItemTemplate>
                <div>
                <asp:Table runat="server" >
                    <asp:TableRow>
                        <asp:TableCell Width="40%">
                            <asp:Label ID="Label17" runat="server" Font-Bold="true" Font-Size="Medium"  Text='<%#Eval("RoomType") %>'></asp:Label>  
                        </asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:TableCell Width="20%">
                             <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Search" /> 
                        </asp:TableCell>
                    </asp:TableRow>
                    <asp:TableRow>
                        <asp:TableCell ColumnSpan="2">
                            <asp:Label ID="Label18" runat="server" Font-Bold="true" Font-Size="Medium" Text='<%#Eval("Description") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </asp:TableCell>
                    </asp:TableRow>
                </asp:Table>
                </div>
             </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:ListView>
```

**C#**

```
     public class Place
            {
                public string RoomType { get; set; }

                public string Description { get; set; }
            }

            List<Place> items = new List<Place>();
                        items.Add(new Place() { RoomType = "RoomType1", Description= "RoomType Description"});
                        items.Add(new Place() { RoomType = "RoomType2", Description = "RoomType Description" });
                        items.Add(new Place() { RoomType = "RoomType3", Description = "RoomType Description" });

  ListView1.DataSource = items;
```

While checking with Break point, i recognize the items list has the items. but i cant get in my page.

[image]

Comment: Where you set the datasource for listview ?

Comment: You need ListView1.DataBind();

Comment: ok yogi, i solved now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the datasource for listview and try the below code

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<Place> items = new List<Place>();
            items.Add(new Place() { RoomType = "RoomType1", Description = "RoomType Description" });
            items.Add(new Place() { RoomType = "RoomType2", Description = "RoomType Description" });
            items.Add(new Place() { RoomType = "RoomType3", Description = "RoomType Description" });
            this.ListView1.DataSource = items;
            this.ListView1.DataBind();
        }
```

Comment: thank you sir, this.ListView1.DataBind(); i miss this

Comment: @Sagotharan cool, mark this as answer if it resolved ur query

Comment: i have tried to mark, but i just updated my qus, so site can't allow to mark immediately.

Comment: next i want to filter my listview,. is i need to remove the list items in C#, or any hidden options there?

Comment: you mean to have pager like control to page the list or you need to filter data bound to list view ?

Comment: s sir, now i have tried filter. if i got any trouble i post it here

Answer (score 2):

I did not see any error. Could you please check your list added or not by writing them to console ?

```
Console.WriteLine();
        foreach (Place item in items)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
```

Please add an foreach function to see.

Comment: thanks sir, i tried this for while i can't the error and output.

Comment: @Sagotharan so the only problem you dont have datasource for listview

Comment: s sir. i didn't notice this