# ListView not displaying at all

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, iqueryable

**Goal:** Get ListView to show. I am simply trying to display rows of data where the IsApproved column has a value of 1 (true)

**Problem:** The ListView is not showing (not the data OR even the headers themself)

**What I've tried**: I've tried debugging and using WriteLine statements to see where its getting caught up. Users is getting a value(the SELECT query), so it's not null.

Remaining question: So if it's getting a value, why is the entire thing not displaying?  I would think at least the headers would display (those are not coming from the database). Is something wrong with my data binding? I also tried adding lstUsers.DataBind(); as per [Listview not shown in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22217782/listview-not-shown-in-asp-net)

This is what was in the WriteLine Output/debug:

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[ID] AS [ID], 
[Extent1].[UserName] AS [UserName], 
[Extent1].[FirstName] AS [FirstName], 
[Extent1].[LastName] AS [LastName], 
[Extent1].[EmailAddress] AS [EmailAddress],     
[Extent1].[IsApproved] AS [IsApproved]
FROM [dbo].[SomeUserRegistration] AS [Extent1]
WHERE [Extent1].[IsApproved] = 1
```

---

When I expand the above in Visual Studio, it says: Empty = "Enumeration yielded no results" but when I do it from GetDataFromQuery() I can see the 3 results from the DB [0] [1] and [2] all have values

---

**c# code:**

```
public IQueryable<SomeUserRegistration> lstUsers_GetData()
        {       
            IQueryable<SomeUserRegistration> users = null;
            users = GetDataFromQuery();

            if (users != null)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(users);
                return users;
            }
            else { return null; }

public IQueryable<SomeUserRegistration> GetDataFromQuery()
        {
            return db.SuperUserRegistrations.Where(m => m.IsApproved);
        }
```

**aspx code:**

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

    <h1>Manage Requests</h1>

    <asp:ListView ID="lstUsers" runat="server" ItemType="Program.PData.SomeUserRegistration" DataKeyNames="ID" SelectMethod="lstUsers_GetData"
        OnItemCommand="lstUsers_ItemCommand" DeleteMethod="lstUsers_DeleteItem" OnSorting="lstUsers_Sorting"
        OnItemDataBound="lstUsers_ItemDataBound"
        ItemPlaceholderID="litPlaceHolder">
        <LayoutTemplate>
            <div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Last Name</th>
                            <th>First Name</th>
                            <th>UserName</th>
                            <th>EmailAddress</th>                          
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <asp:Literal ID="litPlaceHolder" runat="server" />
                </table>
            </div>
        </LayoutTemplate>

        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr>

                <td><%# Item.LastName %></td>
                <td><%# Item.FirstName %></td>
                <td><%# Item.UserName %></td>
                <td><%# Item.EmailAddress %></td>              
            </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
    <%--  </asp:Panel>--%>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: The most logical conclusion would be that `users` is null or does not contain any data. In both cases you would not see the ListView headers.

Comment: Good to know about the headers. But if users was null then how does it get into the conditional block :  "if (users != null)"

Comment: ListViews also have `<EmptyData>` templates fyi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was apparently pointed to a table with the same name, to a database with the same name, on a server with a slightly different name. This coupled with the fact that IsApproved was 0 on the database the code was looking at (as opposed to the db I thought it was looking at).

Lesson: Look very closely into the debugger details. If nothing comes in from the LINQ query then it won't even show headers.